# how to implement read more button in react native ( For RenderHTML )

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using react native render html package to display text in an view I need to implement read more button but I got no idea how to decrease the no of lines in the render HTML text . the description comes from an API So no changes can be done to the HTML Part of the program

This is the code i used to display the HTML :

```
  <RenderHtml
    contentWidth={100}
    source={{ html: item.description }}
    baseStyle={styles.card}
    defaultTextProps={{ numberOfLines: 1 }}
  />
  <Pressable onPress={() => { openArticle(item.feed_id) }}>
    <AppText style={styles.read}> read more</AppText>
  </Pressable>
</View>
<AppText style={styles.feedText}>{item.description}</AppText>}
```

This is the code I tried to implement this but it doesn't work

Comment: Would you please share how the source of renderHtml looks like?

Answer (score -1):

try to set value of `numberOfLines` in variable,and change it after click in button to `null`.